# How can I make the animation to make the character keep walking moving nonstop?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I make the animation loop it will walk a bit and return to the original position and start over from original position. If I don't set it loop it will walk once a bit and stop. But I want it to keep walking nonstop.

Screenshot of the animation inspector :

[image: Animation inspector]

Screenshot of the animator inspector :

[image: Animator inspector]

And the character inspector :

[image: Character inspector]

First I want to know how to make the character walking nonstop using the animation ?

Second how to make the character to stop at specific position after walked some ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the position to be reset when the animation clip loops you can check "Apply root motion" on the animator.

To stop the character after a certain amount of time can be best done through a script. I recommend to add an animation behaviour to the state you want to loop for a certain amount of time and override the onstateenter. In there you can start a coroutine that then can set a trigger in the animator to exit the state.

Comment: I checked the loop on the animation to make it loop over and over again and also checked the apply root motion but it keep going back to the original position and if not making loop only apply root motion it will stop after some walking. Just like before the apply root motion didn't change anything.

Comment: The character and animation both downloaded from Mixamo.com

Comment: @DanielLip Did you bake the animation's root transform position (XZ)? You can find it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/MecanimRootMotion.png). I recommend to also read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Mixamo before you download, you have to tick the box "In Place" below the download button.

Then in Unity you can just loop the animation and it will not jump back to the original position. But doing it this way you'll have to move your character manually.

You could also try setting the asset's Rig import settings to "Humanoid".